# Dynamic Width, Color Series Base On Value TeeChart .Net

Tags: .net, dynamic, charts, teechart, segment

I using Teechart on winform to learn .
I draw line, it have threshold value, i want if Yvalue less or more than threshold value, the line will be have another color and width, it means: have multi color and width on a line. How can i do that ? 
Thanks

I think i can draw each segment but fail:

```
if (line.YValues[i] < 50)
{
   line.ValueColor(i) = Color.Red;  
or
   line.Color = Color.Red;
   line.linepen.width = 3;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Update my question, i want base on Yvalue not Xvalue

Comment: line.ValueColor(i) not accessible in my project winforms :( so sad, someone can help me ?